# With C++20, function with reference argument doesn't accept a tempoary object

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
inline string& rtirm(string& s)
{
    s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(' ') + 1);
    return s;
}

const char* buf = " abc ";
string s_trim = rtirm(string(buf));
```

This code has been working well until I upgraded visual studio to 2022 and with C++20.

> Error C2664   'std::string &rtirm(std::string &)': cannot convert
> argument 1 from 'std::string' to 'std::string &'

I clearly understand the reason -- a reference can't refer to a tempoary object.
But this make the code more complicated. Do I have to define a variable before calling rtirm?

```
string temp{buf};
string s_trim = rtirm(temp);
```

Comment: As an aside, this has nothing to do with changes in the C++20 standard, but  rather that the newer compiler is stricter by default. See the [/permissive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170) option.

Comment: iirc msvc allows to bind temporaries to non-const references as non standard extension in certain circumstances, but I dont know about any details and neither does it explain why it stops working. Though anyhow the code should be fixed

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/z9PTbbM55 so now MSVC behaves like other compilers. Note warring is filed, so if you treat warnings as errors the in older version it will be same.

Answer (score 0):

```
inline string& rtirm(string& s)
{
    s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(' ') + 1);
    return s;
}

inline string rtrim(string&& s)
{
    s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(' ') + 1);
    return s;
}

void test(){
    const char* buf = "    abc    ";
    string sTemp{ buf };
    rtrim(sTemp);
    
    string s_trim = rtrim(string(buf));
}
```

I prefer this, adding a rvalue-reference version, that makes both reference and rvalue-reference arguments working.

Comment: Suppose you do `std::string& s = rtirm(string(buf));` then you are back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have to define a variable and then call rtrim using it instead of temporary object.